# SWIFT: Crash when trying to fetch all Images From Library

Tags: swift, xcode

The app keeps crashing when I attempt to fetch all images from library, the message from debugger is: Terminated due to memory issue

Any idea how can fix it? Here is my code:

```
func fetchImagesFromLibrary() {

    let fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

    fetchResult.enumerateObjects { (object, index, stop) -> Void in
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isSynchronous = false
        options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat

        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: index) as PHAsset, targetSize: self.view.frame.size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFill, options: .none, resultHandler: { (image, _) in


            if let image = image {
                print(image)
                //self.imageview1.image = image

            }
        }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to load all the images with that size `self.view.frame.size`? That doesn't surprise me that it's too much a create a memory issue.

Comment: You are correct, it worked, thank you